# Передать JavaScript'y переменную с РНР

Tags: php, javascript

Вопрос: если сервер уже отдал переменную РНР то как лучше всего передать ее JavaScript'y? Отображать JavaScript в коде страницы например через:

```
echo '<script>
var myVariable = '.$myVariable'.;
...
</script>';
```

со взгляда поисковой оптимизации как известно не совсем правильно — JavaScript нужно подключать внешним файлом

Второе что приходит в голову — использовать на странице скрытое поле:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="myVariableID" value="'.$myVariable.'">';
```

а в js-файле брать его value:

```
var myVariable = document.getElementById('myVariableID').value;
...
```

Есть ли еще идеи?

Comment: Поисковая оптимизация **не должна** приводить к таким костылям в коде. Если у вас, конечно, не SEO головного мозга.

Comment: Лучше всего разделить между собой клиентскую и серверную части и забирать данные с сервера `javascript'ом` через `ajax` запросы.

Comment: как вариант можете генерировать яваскрипт и подключать его как `<script>` тег

Comment: Извините, но мне трудно согласиться с Вашим утверждением о том, что внесение скрипта внутри документа отрицательно сказывается на SEO. Звучит немного нелепо. Например Ваш (и не только Ваш) случай - это реально обоснованная причина внести скрипт именно внутри `<body>`. Так почему поисковые системы должны рассматривать это как неграмотный подход? См. также [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358206/seo-implications-of-including-style-and-script-tags-inside-body) обсуждение по этому поводу. Также предлагаю открыть код https://stackoverflow.com/ и убедится в наличии нескольких скриптов вн

Comment: Это не мое утверждение, это то что я читал. А равняться на других это не ответ на вопрос: как правильно. Обратите внимание на цитату по ссылке [devaka.ru](https://devaka.ru/articles/seo-slicing): _"Казалось бы, сами поисковые системы не заботятся о качестве HTML кода, подавая пример другим вебмастерам, и в нём можно найти много стилей и скриптов, не вынесенных во внешний файл"_.

Comment: @stckvrw Перед нами не стоит вопрос "как правильно". (Несомненно, в Вашем случае правильно вставить скрипт внутри. Это намного элегантнее чем делать запрос через ajax или искать другие костыли). Вопрос практический - как это повлияет на SEO. На практический вопрос отвечаем практикой - смотрим как делают на сайтах с отличным SEO подходом. (Кстати, при поиске "seo <script> inside" указанный сайт выходит первым. Там же люди пишут, что на SEO это не влияет. Хотя Выше право рассматривать это как курьез).

Comment: @stckvrw, да выкиньте вы уже те ресурсы, которые убеждают вас, что вставка кода в HTML влияет на поисковую выдачу. Если бы влияло -- никто не вставлял бы в разметку кучу счетчиков от google, yandex, mail и прочего рекламного барахла.

Comment: Одни пишут что влияет, другие — нет, а кто прав... Вот [здесь](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/08/seo-and-javascript-dos-and-donts/) например пишут что большие куски Джаваскрипта (а я имел в виду именно большие, а не скрипты счетчиков) вынуждают паука дольше индексировать страницу. И по их словам _"the harder the spider has to work, the lower your potential search engine rank"_. Если это уже неактуально (статья за 2012) тогда приведите хоть какую то свежую ссылку

Comment: @s976, по вашей ссылке на stackoverflow пишут что скрипты не влияет на SEO потому что поисковики их игнорируют. Но это неправда. С 2008 Гугл уже научился их читать, так что влияют ли большие куски скриптов на SEO опять же спорный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

В качестве примера.
Создаем файл `variables.php`

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
$js_vars = array(
    'lang' => array(
        'max_enter' => 'Осталось знаков',
    )
);
foreach ($js_vars as $var_name => $data) {
    echo "var {$var_name} = ".json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE).";\n";
}
```

Подключим (до ваших скриптов)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/variables.php"></script>
```

P.S Если используйте роуты, можно изменить расширение `.php` на `.js` (или через `rewrite`)

Получаем результат в JS

```
lang['max_enter']
```